# Using different ArcMap licenses on same computer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, license, virtual-machine

I am currently a GIS analyst for a company and use their ArcMap Desktop license on my computer.

I am also considering working part-time for another company, who also would give me an ArcMap Desktop license. It would be A LOT easier to be able to have these on the same computer.

Is it possible in any way to use two different licenses on the same computer? I know I can't install two versions of the software on the same machine, but is it possible to switch between licenses when desired without major issues?

Or could I just force myself to use ArcGIS Pro for one company (which I really am trying to do anyways) and ArcMap for the other?

I definitely don't want to violate any licensing rules (like using one license to do the other company's work), but I also don't want to have to lug around two computers if I can avoid it.

Comment: Have you tried using the two different licenses on the same computer?

Comment: What type of licenses, single-use or concurrent-use (floating)?

Comment: one easy way would be to install a VM on your PC and then install the other ESRI software on that.

Comment: It's not possible to install two different *releases* of ArcGIS Desktop on the same host. If the employers are sponsoring different *levels* of licenses (e.g., Advanced and Editor), then that would be trivial -- just use GIS Manager to change levels.

Comment: Yes, Vince, the employers will be sponsoring two different levels of single-use licenses (one Advanced, one Basic). So I can manage all of this in ArcGIS Administrator? Would I simply just change the license used within the ArcGIS Administrator every time I do work for each company? (I know this seems simple, but I just want to make sure I don't accidentally mess anything up!)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you should be able to do all the things you are exploring to do between the two different licenses. It doesn't appear that using different licenses on the same computer would be violating any Esri licensing rules. Based on [ArcGIS Desktop license types](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/licensing-arcgis-pro.htm)

> A Single Use license authorizes one person to use ArcGIS Desktop, optionally including ArcGIS Pro, on one machine, such as a desktop computer. The license also authorizes the same person to use ArcGIS Desktop on a second machine, such as a laptop computer. However, the software may not be used on both machines at the same time.
>
> A Single Use license can be transferred to a different machine used by a different individual by deauthorizing the license on the currently authorized machine and repeating the authorization process on the new machine.
>
> It is not necessary to sign in to use ArcGIS Pro with a Single Use license. However, it is necessary to sign in with ArcGIS account credentials to access content from ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise.